# how to add text on off inside the toggle switch with angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

on off toggle switch is working with the ng-model data. but how to show the on off status inside the toggle switch

html

```
  {{pump1status_switch}}
 <label class="switch">
 <input type="checkbox" ng-model="pump1status.value1">
 <span class="slider round"></span>
 </label>
```

angular js code

```
  if ($scope.pump1status.trim() === "1") {
                $scope.pump1status = "1";
                $scope.pump1status_switch = "on";
                $scope.pump1status = {
                    value1: true,
                    value2: 'YES'
                };
            }
            else {
                $scope.pump1status_switch = "off";
                $scope.pump1status = "0";
                $scope.pump1status = {
                    value1: false,
                    value2: 'NO'
                };
            }
```

[image: toggle switch]

Comment: Is this a css issue? Do you have a sample demo?

Comment: its not css issue, i just  want to put the on/off inside the switch, is there any good way to show on or off in the toggle switch?

Comment: We don't know what css/library you are using, so it is very difficult for someone to help

Comment: please check this link https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GCX7K5PFK8UP

Comment: i can display the on/off data with  {{pump1status_switch}}.

Comment: Do you have an example image of what you're trying to achieve? Depending on what you want, the solution could be very different.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GCX814SJH6F6 i want to show like this. but off is hiding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another span element for the text and use `ng-class` to give it an extra class if switch is off:

```
<label class="switch">
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.isActive">
   <span class="slider round" >
       <span ng-class="{ 'off': !vm.isActive }">{{vm.isActive ? 'on' : 'off'}}</span>
   </span>
 </label>
```

Then you will need some css to move the `off` text:

```
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
  padding: 7px;
}

.off {
   margin-left:26px;
}
```

Check here a working demo: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/k86g0aep/)